# Проблема с кодировкой в SQL Shell (psql)

Tags: sql, postgresql, shell, psql

Проблема с кодировкой в SQL Shell (psql)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: PowerShell пробовал?

Answer (score 0):

Откройте консоль Windows и сначала смените кодировку командой `/c chcp 1251`, а уже потом заходите в SQL Shell.

Comment: Попробувал, не помогло

Comment: Посмотрите [здесь] (https://iu5bmstu.top/index.php/PostgreSQL_-_%D0%9A%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0_%D0%B2_psql_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4_Windows)